# Section inline with styled aside element?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm attempting to align a `section` element with a styled `aside` element. I've tried all combinations of `inline`, `block`, and `inline-block` but I can't seem to get anything to happen. I don't understand why it's not aligning as it should.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmgkB/

Visually, this is the result:

[image]

...that I want to get (approximately) here:

[image]

HTML excerpt:

```
<aside class="icon"><p>§</p></aside> 
    <section role="region" class="aside">
        Welcome to the Pyroneous Lair. There is a variety of features here. 
    </section>
```

CSS excerpt:

```
@charset UTF-8;

body
{
  background:#000;
  color:#FFF;
  width:90%;
  font:11px tahoma, sans-serif, serif;
  margin:auto
}

article,aside,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section
{
  display:block
}

header
{
  text-align:center
}

hr
{
  border:none;
  border-top:medium double #333;
  color:#FFF;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0
}

hr:after
{
  content:"§";
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  top:-.85em;
  font-size:1.5em;
  background:#000;
  z-index:2;
  padding:0 .25em
}

.icon
{
  font:45px serif, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  color:#000;
  border-radius:100px;
  text-align:center;
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  background:#A60000
}

.aside
{
  margin-left:5%;
  display:inline
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make both the `.aside` and the `.icon` be `display:inline-block` (*and remove the `p` from inside the `icon` as it offers nothing..*)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/bmgkB/2/